# Edit existing Visualforce Page (ApexPage) using AndrewFawcett ToolingAPI package

Tags: visualforce, metadata-api, metadata, tooling-api

In APEX there is great wrapper class to access the ToolingAPI written by Andrew Fawcett https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi

There are a lot of examples including one which shows how to **edit** an ApexClass. It uses a ToolingAPI.MetadataContainer to hold an ToolingAPI.ApexClassMember. This works great and is very fast.

Now I would like to adopt the same pattern to edit an ApexPage unsing again a ToolingAPI.MetadataContainer but now containing a ToolingAPI.ApexPageMember. Unfortunately this fails. Looking at the code of ToolingAPI.cls there are obvious differences.

Let's have a look on **ToolingAPI.ApexClassMember**

```
   public class ApexClassMember extends SObject_x implements ISerialize {
        public String            body;
        public String            content;
        public ApexClass         contentEntity;
        public String            contentEntityId;
        public Datetime          lastSyncDate;
        public ApexClassMetadata metadata;
        public MetadataContainer metadataContainer;
        public Id                metadataContainerId;        
        public SymbolTable       symbolTable;
        public ApexClassMember() {
            super(SObjectType.ApexClassMember);
        }
        public override void serialize(JSONGenerator jsonGen) {
            super.serialize(jsonGen);
            if(body!=null)
                jsonGen.writeStringField('body', body);
            if(content!=null)
                jsonGen.writeStringField('content', content);
            if(contentEntity!=null)
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('contentEntity', contentEntity);
            if(contentEntityId!=null)
                jsonGen.writeStringField('contentEntityId', contentEntityId);
            if(lastSyncDate!=null)
                jsonGen.writeDateTimeField('lastSyncDate', lastSyncDate);
            if(metadata!=null)
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('metadata', metadata);
            if(metadataContainer!=null)
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('metadataContainer', metadataContainer);
            if(metadataContainerId!=null)
                jsonGen.writeStringField('metadataContainerId', metadataContainerId);
            if(symbolTable!=null)
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('symbolTable', symbolTable);
        }
    }
```

Compared to **ToolingAPI.ApexPageMember** grabbed directly from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi/master/src/classes/ToolingAPI.cls (as of 2014-07-09 20:00 CEST) it's quite less:

```
public class ApexPageMember extends SObject_x{
    public String            body;
    public String            content;
    public ApexPage          contentEntity;
    public String            contentEntityId;
    public DateTime          lastSyncDate;
    public Metadata          metadata;
    public MetadataContainer metadataContainer;
    public Id                metadataContainerId;
    public ApexPageMember() {
        super(SObjectType.ApexPageMember);
    }
}
```

Obviously the implementation of ISerialize is missing and the override of serialize(JSONGenerator jsonGen) which seem to be crucial to get the proper callout compiled. I suppose this is "under construction".

So what has to be done to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could be interesting for @AndyFawcett (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/286/andrew-fawcett) the author of ToolingAPI.cls. I just changed the code like this:

```
 public class ApexPageMember extends SObject_x  implements ISerialize {
    public String            body;
    public String            content;
    public ApexPage          contentEntity;
    public String            contentEntityId;
    public DateTime          lastSyncDate;
    public Metadata          metadata;
    public MetadataContainer metadataContainer;
    public Id                metadataContainerId;
    public ApexPageMember() {
        super(SObjectType.ApexPageMember);
    }
    public override void serialize(JSONGenerator jsonGen) {
        super.serialize(jsonGen);
        if(body!=null)
            jsonGen.writeStringField('body', body);
        if(content!=null)
            jsonGen.writeStringField('content', content);
        if(contentEntity!=null)
            jsonGen.writeObjectField('contentEntity', contentEntity);
        if(contentEntityId!=null)
            jsonGen.writeStringField('contentEntityId', contentEntityId);
        if(lastSyncDate!=null)
            jsonGen.writeDateTimeField('lastSyncDate', lastSyncDate);
        if(metadata!=null)
            jsonGen.writeObjectField('metadata', metadata);
        if(metadataContainer!=null)
            jsonGen.writeObjectField('metadataContainer', metadataContainer);
        if(metadataContainerId!=null)
            jsonGen.writeStringField('metadataContainerId', metadataContainerId);
    }
}
```

and it works fine for me calling it like that:

```
 ToolingAPI.ApexPageMember apexPageMember = new ToolingAPI.ApexPageMember(); // Create ApexPageMember and associate them with the MetadataContainer     
 apexPageMember.Body                = fileSaveBody;
 apexPageMember.ContentEntityId     = item.id;
 apexPageMember.MetadataContainerId = containerId;      
 ToolingAPI.SaveResult apexClassMemberSaveResult = tool.createSObject(apexPageMember);
```

If someone notice anything I was missing, please let me know.

Comment: The code is up on github and I'm sure @andrewfawcett would love community help with issues. Have you submitted a pull request with your changes to he can incorporate them into the master package?

Comment: @AndrewFawcett you are welcome! If you patch the ToolingAPI.cls, please also have a look at ApexComponentMember, where the same changes should be applied. After that in my tests I was also able to save components. Let me know, if you have any questions. Thanks again for that Class, it really rocks!