# Are there any plans to update ToolingAPI.cls for APEX to v32 in order to support Lightning Components?

Tags: apex, tooling-api, lightning-aura-components

Unlike [MetadataAPI](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) the [ToolingAPI](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi) APEX class still refers to version 30. Please note this question is not about ToolingAPI itself, but about the APEX wrapper class project to make ToolingAPI available for native apps from within APEX. In order to use it for Lightning components, it would be great to update this to the current version 32.

Are there any plans to do so in the near future? Are there any major challenges to overcome on the way to this update? Are you looking for contributors / maintainers in order to do so?

I will start to look into it on my own. There are some mandatory changes and just setting TOOLING_API_URI to '/services/data/v32.0/tooling' is not enough to make the old functionality work. Also I'll update my question here with any further conclusions.

Also for version v30 I have a couple of recommendations for patches I've done so far. I started to use it at v29 and needed to make some small changes:

- to update ApexPages, I patched `class ApexPageMember` ([details](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42736/edit-existing-visualforce-page-apexpage-using-andrewfawcett-toolingapi-package) and [github-issue](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi/issues/20))
- to update ApexComponents, I patched `class ApexComponentMember` (same issue as for ApexPages)
- to update Trigges, I patched `class ApexTrigger` (changed type for `tableEnumOrId` from `Id` to `String`)
- to retrieve syntax information about constructors, I patched `class SymbolTable` (changed type for `constructors` from `Symbol[]` to `Constructor[]`)

In parallel to this question, I'll try my best to provide my suggestions also as issues on github.

Any insights on the future of ToolingAPI.cls are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should file an issue on that github repo. You can do that here: https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi/issues. You could then reference this question, if you'd like one of the contributors to that project to comment here.

Comment: Did so already https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi/issues/20 - so far I made good progress with patching and I'll provide my working version to anyone who's interested.

Comment: I have updated Apex Metadata API to v32.0, and tried to use it create Lightning Components, sadly ran into a platform bug, SF have filed a bug for it, i hope it will be fixed soon. I've note as yet tried with Tooling API. I'll review your issue on the GitHub repo and refer back here.

Comment: @AndrewFawcett : for me MetadataAPI works fine (but very slow) for Lightning. But I found a **super fast** approach using PATCH ToolingAPI calls via JavaScript as described here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57616/calling-toolingapi-to-save-an-auradefinition-using-patch-via-javascript-possible - I'm going to provide examples and a tutorial for it on my blog. In the meantime I can provide code snippets or insights to anyone on request. As Doug Chasman said in the link above, they did something really different and I would say the result is lightning fast! :-)

Comment: Interesting, this is my Aura example with Metadata API, it currently gives a gack (internal salesforce code), https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls#L958. Curious how yours looks?

Comment: My team is investigating the issue that @AndrewFawcett has run into. I was not the dev that grabbed the case/bug from the queue but I am checking with him now on status/progress etc. I suspect this is usage error but nothing jumped out at me and the error he is getting is not very helpful.

Comment: OK - no progress on this one so I have just grabbed it and am starting to dig now.

Comment: @DougChasman your a star, thanks so much! Uwe you mentioned above you have Metadata API working, can you share how please?

Comment: @AndrewFawcett I use a very old-school pattern based on jszip and deploy and retrieve for the entire bundle. Slow as hell. I will create and answer a separate question to provide more infos if you like. Let's keep this one here better focused on ToolingAPI.

Comment: @DougChasman and @ Andrew: I would recommend that we cover MetadataAPI at this question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/58153/how-can-we-access-lightning-components-via-metadatasevice-cls-from-within-apex-a and keep this one here for ToolingAPI. Make sense?

Comment: @UweHeim I've updated the Apex Tooling API project to use SOAP rather than REST, could you check whether or not you could handle your lightning scenario with the newer version?  There are some (see very few) Aura components within the metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a [GitHub issue to track the update to API 32.0](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/issues/63), but am of course open to contributions if some progress has already been started. :-)

**Background to process of updating it.** Myself and co-author James Loghry chose to go the REST API wrapping route originally, because the WSDL contains so much polymorphic types the Apex to WSDL tool doesn't support. However the implication of this decision is its not as quick to upgrade as the Apex Metadata API (which although still needs some tweaking currently does not need no where near the same amount the generated Tooling class would need).

**Thoughts on switching to SOAP as part of the upgrade...** Basically the approach we took originally and may take again to upgrade now is to leverage the fact that the types that do get generated from the WSDL to Apex process are similar enough to the JSON structures to act as a starting point to be pasted into ToolingAPI.cls and stripped from some of the XML metadata data. That said, i am interested in if we could revisit using the SOAP version of the Tooling API, by leveraging the fact that Apex to WSDL is now open source and we can potentially fix the issue that prevented us using the SOAP API in the first place. Also we've discovered that the REST API is not bulkified, so you end up using a lot more API calls.

Comment: I had here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57534/patching-toolingapi-cls-for-v31-how-to-query-for-deploydetails-at-containerasy a longer discussion with @DanielBallinger. He provided there a ToolingAPI.cls created with his FuseIT (more the SOAP approach). I mixed that manually with your old v30 and the resulting Mixup did even work for me, at least somehow. I really like the REST style. So if maintainable, I would prefer it over SOAP. But since we have no PATCH in APEX, the fastest methods may be not usable - at all. And there again comes JavaScript with PATCH...

Comment: re: Making a PATCH call form Apex, does applying ?_HttpMethod=PATCH to the Tooling API REST endpoint not work then?